# How to get Minecraft mods?

Tags: minecraft-mods

I have no clue on how to get the mods for Minecraft.  I have looked up on how to do it before but I just don't understand it as it's so complicated and hard to understand.

Could someone please help me figure out how to get mods for Minecraft?

Comment: Try reading [this](http://www.minecraftmods.com/how-to-install-minecraft-forge/) and [this](http://www.minecraftmods.com/how-to-install-mods-for-minecraft-forge/). It's not all that complicated. Just give it some time.

Comment: When you want people to help you, you need to explain *what exactly your problem is*. When you say that you "just don't understand" we have no idea what to write, because it could be just as ununderstandable to you as whatever you read before. When you are looking for help to understand something, you need to say *what you read* and *which parts you didn't understand* and *what you didn't understood about it*.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better, slightly more difficult version, and an easy, not as good version.

**Method 1:** Download forge, from [here](http://files.forge.net), and then press the Windows key + R, and enter in `%appdata%`. Press enter. Go into the .Minecraft folder. You should see a folder named "Mods." If you don't, right click inside the .Minecraft folder, and go to New > Folder, and name this folder "Mods." Now, you can put your mods in this folder. Mods come in the form of .jar files. To get started, try installing the [Securitycraft Mod](http://www.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/securitycraft-mod/2233674)!

**Method 2:** Go to [skydaz](http://www.skydaz.com) and download an installer for almost and mod you would like! :D

Comment: Should use a different mod as example for our new player. ;) For example, a minimap mod.

Answer (score 0):

I have modded minecraft many times now, and the Easiest way that I found is to download Minecraft Forge, found [Here.](http://files.minecraftforge.net/)

After installing Minecraft Forge, you should press the Windows + R and type in `AppData`. After doing that, look for the Roaming folder and at the top/near the top of the Roaming folder, you should find the .Minecraft folder. Inside of that there will be a Mods folder, and that is where you put your Mods.

EDIT: While in the minecraft launcher, go to profiles and there should be a forge Profile.